# Visual Web Developer is missing from Web Platform Installer 3?

Tags: visual-web-developer, web-platform-installer

Call me blind but how exactly do we suppose to install Visual Web Developer with Web Platform Installer 3? There is no such an option. The other options do not install it, e.g. WebMatrix, MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

Open Web PI and type `Visual Web Developer` in the search textbox, hit enter. If it is supported on your platform, you will see it in search results.